# Where is the remote debugging option in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, remote-access, fedora-19

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging/Firefox_for_Android), the remote debugging option should be right in **Tools -> Web developer -> Connect...**, however, I can see no "Connect" option in the "Web developer" menu:

[image: Screenshot of Web developer menu]

Where can it possibly be? I have Fedora 19, Firefox was installed from the repos.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `about:config` and set the `devtools.debugger.remote-enabled` to `true`. End of story.

By the way, is `false` really the default for all platforms?